# Order, Product and OrdersProduct models associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I am building a rails app in where I need to have Product and Order models.

I think the logical path is to have another model, called OrdersProduct, since a Order can have many products to be ordered, in which I put a `product_id`, `order_id` (matching the two other models) and an `amount` field.

Well, my problem is how can I access each single product information from my OrdersProduct record?

The point is I can do a `belongs_to :product` association into my `OrdersProduct` model, but it doesn't makes any sense to put a `has_many :orders_products` in my `Product` model.

Models seems something like this:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  # id
  # name
  # etc…
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  # id
  # name
  # etc…
end

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  # id
  # customer_id
  # etc…
end

class OrdersProduct < ActiveRecord::Base
  # order_id
  # product_id
  # amount
end
```

What's the best way to have access to `Order.products` and get a collection of products related to the OrdersProduct model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is to use [Has and belongs to many through](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has-many-through-and-has-and-belongs-to-many) association.

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders_products
  has_many :products, through: :orders_products
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders_products
  has_many :orders, through: :orders_products
end

class OrdersProduct < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order
  belongs_to :product
end
```

Now in commerce terminology, ordered products are often referenced as `LineItem` so instead of using `orders_products` table you could specify `line_items` table.

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :line_items
  has_many :products, through: :line_items
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :line_items
  has_many :orders, through: :line_items
end

class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order
  belongs_to :product
end
```

Comment: Thank you, very precise. I will try it in a bit!

Comment: what is `def Order < ActiveRecord::Base`?

Comment: Thanks for noticing mistake. I was rushing when I was typing my answer.

Comment: This is working pretty sweet. Thank you Jozef. Also for the LineItem tip. I'm not english, but I preffer to write my code all in english and don't knew this before.

Answer (score -1):

You can get rid of the `OrdersProduct` model.

Just need the following models:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders
  # id
  # name
  # etc…
end

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
  has_many :products

  # id
  # customer_id
  # etc…
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order

  # id
  # name
  # order_id
  # etc…
end
```

So now you can call `customer.orders.first.products` or `order.products` given that `customer` and `order` are instances.

Comment: Dont think this helps. You need join model to handle many-to-many relationship and to keep track additional information on a connection (ammount, discount, etc).

Comment: Nowhere, and thats why I dont think it helps.

Comment: I think this is typical usecase for many-to-many relationship. Do you wanna create new record for Product each time your user add it to Order? Where will you get the Product details/information then? If you dont trust me, check out github.com/spree/spree how they handle the online store.